# At which level do return statements need to be written if there is also an 'if' statement above it?

Tags: python, return, indentation

Let me preface this by saying that I am fairly new to coding, so be gentle.

I have been writing the following:

```
def execute_move(player, house_choice, houses):

next_house=houses[house_choice]
chosen_house=houses[house_choice-1]
chosen_house_seeds=chosen_house[1]
for i in range(chosen_house_seeds):
    if player=='P1': # skips the store of the opposite player
        if next_house==houses[13]:
            next_house_index=houses.index(next_house) 
            new_nhi=next_house_index+1
            next_house=houses[new_nhi]
    elif player=='P2':
        if next_house==houses[6]:
            next_house_index=houses.index(next_house) 
            new_nhi=next_house_index+1
            next_house=houses[new_nhi]
    [(next_house[0], (next_house[1]+1)) if x==next_house else x for x in houses]
    next_house_index=houses.index(next_house) 
    new_nhi=next_house_index+1
    next_house=houses[new_nhi] 
[(chosen_house[0], (chosen_house[1]-chosen_house_seeds)) if x==chosen_house else x for x in houses]
return houses
```

My aim is to replace some of the tuples in the list 'houses', and then return the new list of tuples.

For some reason the var I assign the call to later on in the code only produces the original list when printed.

Im thinking that it may have something to do with the indentation of the 'if' statements or the indentation of the return statement.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing intrinsically special about a `return` statement when compared to other Python statements.

As such, you should *indent* it as you would any other (i.e., by placing the `return` line  inside the block that makes sense in your specific algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Any control structure (such as an if statement) expects the next line to be indented.  The control structure ends when the code begins to go back to the original level

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

```
def function(input):
    input = input * 2
    if (input > 5):
        input * 2
        return input
    input +1
    return input
```

so in this case, if the input is < 2.5, it is returned doubled + 1.  If it is >2.5 it is returned * 4

It is probably just a bad cut and paste, but the body of the function must be indented as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension statements, those that look like `[(next_house[0], ...]` are building lists but it's not assigned to anything so it is being discarded.  Try setting result to a variable...

```
list_of_next_house_tuples = [(next_house[0], (next_house[1]+1)) if x==next_house else x for x in houses]
```

Then determine what you are going to do with this new list.

Comment: Thank you! That was the fix.